# Transport endpoint is not connected in Colab Pro+

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am a google colab pro+ user. I am trying to train a DL model and getting an error of **"Transport endpoint is not connected"**, while training the model. I ve been using the pro version previously and faced the same error so I thought of upgrading but it didnt help as well. The code was running fine for 3hrs and everytime it is around 3-4hrs, I face the error.

I tried to keep the runtime continue using a javascript and it was working fine. The full error info is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
 18% 54466/300000 [3:57:19<17:49:51,  3.83it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Ub4D/exp_runner.py", line 998, in <module>
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Ub4D/exp_runner.py", line 257, in train
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py", line 391, in add_scalar
    self._get_file_writer().add_summary(summary, global_step, walltime)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py", line 113, in add_summary
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorboard/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 244, in run
    self.add_event(event, global_step, walltime)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py", line 98, in add_event
    self._run()
    self.event_writer.add_event(event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorboard/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 117, in add_event
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorboard/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 275, in _run
    self._record_writer.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorboard/summary/writer/record_writer.py", line 40, in write
    self._async_writer.write(event.SerializeToString())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorboard/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 171, in write
    self._writer.write(header + header_crc + data + footer_crc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 101, in write
    self._check_worker_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorboard/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 212, in _check_worker_status
    self._writable_file.append(
    raise exception
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: exp/Cactus/paper_config/logs/events.out.tfevents.1691166619.f28574666dfe.12707.0; Transport endpoint is not connected
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorboard/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 244, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorboard/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 275, in _run
    self._record_writer.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorboard/summary/writer/record_writer.py", line 40, in write
    self._writer.write(header + header_crc + data + footer_crc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 101, in write
    self._writable_file.append(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: exp/Cactus/paper_config/logs/events.out.tfevents.1691166619.f28574666dfe.12707.0; Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Seems to me that the problem appears to be related with logging path. Maybe too long logging path. I changed my Trainer parameters so that the default_root_dir is left as default (which is the current path the notebook is running on) and the code seems to run fine. Haven`t got the error past six hours.